# Return a promise result in order using the library dom-to-image

Tags: javascript, promise

Using the [dom-to-image library](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) we can convert an image using Promises.

Usage example, conversion from DOM object to PNG image:

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```

Behind the scenes, the toPng method is chain of a Promise object:

```
/**
 * @param {Node} node - The DOM Node object to render
 * @param {Object} options - Rendering options, @see {@link toSvg}
 * @return {Promise} - A promise that is fulfilled with a PNG image data URL
 * */
function toPng(node, options) {
    return draw(node, options || {})
        .then(function (canvas) {
            return canvas.toDataURL();
        });
}
```

I want to convert images based on a Node array, and then, to get that images in order. The problem is when I call `toPng()` the async process time varies in function of the DOM target complexity. So it will return before the pages with less complexity, instead of return the pages in order.

```
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');

pages.forEach(page => {
  let dataUrl = convertToPng(page.firstElementChild);
});

function convertToPng(page) {
  domtoimage.toPng(page)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      console.log(page); // prints pages randomly (e.g. page3, page1, page2) 
    })
}
```

A possible solution would be use a `Promise.all()` method and attach with a `forEach()` method all the Promises. But in this case, that I'm using an external library, I don't know how to approach in order to get first the page1, then the page 2, and so on...

Comment: chain the promises perhaps? I assume you want to wait until page1 is "complete" before beginning on page2 etc?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I want to wait until page1 is complete, before beginning with the next page.

Comment: If you want to be really hip, try using `async / await`

Comment: @Keith I know `async / await` but I don't know how to apply it in this library.

Comment: `for (const page of pages) { await convertToPng(page.firstElementChild); }`

Comment: ps.. Also make sure you return your promise from `convertToPng`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand for this case you can use `Promise.all`. Smthing like this one:

```
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');

Promise.all(Array.prototype.slice.call(pages,0)
.map(page =>domtoimage.toPng(page))
).then(pages=>{.... your handler....});
```

More information about Promise.all you can get from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Seeing as OP is clearly using modern JS - why not `Promise.all(Array.from(pages, page =>domtoimage.toPng(page))).then(pages => { ... })` :p

Comment: May be I'm a little bit orthodoxal :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't understand why to use `array.slice` or `array.from` if `querySelectorAll` returns an array object. @JaromandaX. Edit: ok it's a `NodeList` that I've always considered as the same as an array, but it only inherit the `forEach` method.

Comment: it doesn't return an Array .. it's a `NodeList` ... with limited array like functionality (i.e. it has a `length` property, and in some modern browsers a `.forEach`, `.keys`, `.values`  and `.entries` methods ... but no `.map` method - which is vital for the code presented to work)

Comment: I used this solution. however, the order of the array items is always wrong no matter if I reverse it or not.. How can I fix the order issue?

Comment: Look, Promise.all(...) return _Array_/_Iterable_  in the same order as it will be ingested into Promise.all(...). The way how you edit my answer you just rewrite the original question. So, I rolled back your changes.

Comment: @DarrylRN. Brief example in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x37p0sae/

The second line is what you try to do. Values will be printed in the same order as timeout will be resolved
The third line is a current solution. Values will be printed in the same order as they persist in the array.

Comment: Hi @VasylMoskalov, when I try your solution .then after .map, I got this `Array.prototype.slice.call(...).sort(...).map(...).then is not a function`. Also in your example, did you miss one closing parentheses?

Comment: @DarrylRN, look. 
Promise.all(...).then(...), not slice(...).sort(...).map(...).then(...)

Comment: okay, thank you @VasylMoskalov

Answer (score 3):

Using `async`/`await`:

HTML:

```
<div class="page">Hello 1</div>
<div class="page">Hello 2</div>
<div class="page">Hello 3</div>
<div class="page">Hello 4</div>
```

JS ([JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/GorkaHernandezDG/5khjzfnp/12/)):

```
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');

async function getPageUrls() {
    for (let page of pages) {
        const url = await convertToPng(page);
        console.log(url);
    }
}

async function convertToPng(page) {
    return await domtoimage.toPng(page);
}

getPageUrls();
```

Based off OPs sample ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GorkaHernandezDG/9csoqj1v/1/)):

```
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');

for (let page of pages) {
    convertToPng(page);
}

async function convertToPng(page) {
    const dataUrl = await domtoimage.toPng(page);
    console.log(dataUrl);
}

getPageUrls();
```

With this solution code execution is stopped until `convertToPng` yields a result at each iteration.

Comment: Seen as your using `async / await`, get rid of that thenable.. :)

Comment: @Keith You're absolutely right! Updated the sample code, thanks!

Comment: Nearly.. :),..  `async function convertToPng(page) { const dataUrl = await domtoimage.toPng(page); console.log(page); }`  If were copying the OP..  Of course he has not yet used dataUrl, but one assumes he will want too.  He may even want to return.. atm. he doesn't. strange I know.. :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I was trying to make it a bit more reusable by returning the result rather than logging it out within the function, fair point nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to chain the promises so they run in sequence is using Array#reduce

```
pages.reduce((promise, page) => 
    promise.then(() => convertToPng(page.firstElementChild)),
    Promise.resolve() // this starts the chain
);
```

This will, as you stated in the comment `wait until page1 is complete, before beginning with the next page`

Though, I get the feeling it's only the output order that is important, in which case the answer by @VasylMoskalov is more appropriate

> As @Keith pointed out in a comment - convertToPng does not return anything (let alone a promise)

```
function convertToPng(page) {
//vvvvvv important you return the promise here
  return domtoimage.toPng(page)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      console.log(page); // prints pages randomly (e.g. page3, page1, page2) 
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation of what will do the array? I understand the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) but I don't know why and how it works. Thank you

Comment: As far As I know Promise.all *preserves* order

Comment: this creates a promise chain ... I didn't show one thing though, so that may clear it up

Comment: @VasylMoskalov - yes, the array resolved by Promise.all preserves the order of the input array to Promise.all - and I think your answer is probably more appropriate, as the asynch stuff is done "as fast as possible" , where as this code, it's done one at a time

Comment: From what the OP said, yours is correct.. -> `yes I want to wait until page1 is complete,`

Comment: I understand, but perhaps the OP was too quick to agree to my interpretation :p

Comment: `convertToPng does not return anything`,  When I first started using promises this always got me caught out.  It's why I think `async / await` was one of the best features brought into JS.  eg.  say I created a promise to do something, but wasn't bothered with the result, in my head the concept of return didn't spring to mind.  But of course a promise to do something, even if not returing anything still needs to return you the promise to do it, otherwise your can't wait for it, and worse catch any errors.  :)

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry for the misinterpretation, I want to preserve the order of the pages, and I said that because I thought that it would be the best way to not complicate the question, but yes, I want the most efficient way to order the pages. In any case, I'm trying to understand your answer. I'm new in JavaScript and I want to learn all about it.

Comment: Vasyl's answer is better ... Gorka's answer is most modern technique though