# Uncaught (in promise) dom-to-image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, qlikview, qliksense

I have a page that has multiple canvas html elements. The website is actually built in angularjs and there are charts that are displayed on it which have been created in Qlik. I am trying to get a screenshot of the individual charts which are rendered as canvas elements on the browser.

Using https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image, I am able to get the screenshot of just first chart using the following code:

```
var node = document.getElementById(divToPrint);
    domtoimage.toPng(node)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = divToPrint + '.png';
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.click();
        });
```

However, for all other charts, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}
Promise.then (async)
```

I found somebody already posted this on github but there is no answer:
https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues/181

Is there something missing in the code?

Comment: I've never used that library, but it seems you're supposed to use the dataUrl as the src of an image element. It is a "data:" URL, i.e. it is an encoding of the actual bytes that make up the image. I'm drawing this conclusion from looking at the sample on the project's page.

Comment: This will allow the user to download the image. Example on the projects's page is for JPEG image and I am using it to save as PNG image: Save and download a compressed JPEG image:

domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('my-node'), { quality: 0.95 })
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
    });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926412/return-a-promise-result-in-order-using-the-library-dom-to-image - It might be related but I am not familiar with the Promise object.

Comment: Given the github issue is closed, did you ask how they solved it?

Comment: are u using qlikview or qliksense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you don't need **filesaver**

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('areaChart'), { quality: 0.95 })
.then(function (dataUrl) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'area-chart.png';
    link.href = dataUrl;
    link.click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image.
Below is the simple code for that.

```
var node = document.getElementById(divToPrint);
domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('node'))
    .then(function (blob) {
        saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
    });
```

But you have to use fileSaver.js for that. You can get it from here https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

and import it as `import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`. in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.Please make sure div is applied to div and not to svg, g or any other tag.If your node is written in ts file, then i would recommend trying placing the node in html file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else has this issue...

My problem was that I had a malformed HTML file and that was causing dom-to-image to fail to make a correct image.

I was able to find this by changing the DIV I was making an image of until I was able to narrow down the section that was causing the problem.  Once I was able to see the section having the issue, it was easy to see the typo.  Once corrected, the dom-to-image worked perfectly!